# facetracking: how to track markers manually which Blender does not recognize?

Tags: tracking, motion-capture

I am trying to track some tracking markers on a face. A part of the clip works very well but at some frames, Blender does not recognize the tracking points at all. Is there a way to track those points manually and tell the motion tracking boxes where to go, even if the program does not recognize the point as a tracking marker?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: yes you can select the tracking marker at any frame and press `G` to move it wherever you like and then step continue to track or manually do it for every frame. i always do that.

Comment: I know the g shortcut but how can I define I point if Blender doesn't see it (eg because of motion blur? there must be a way to make that "keyframe" for the frame.

Comment: you mean how to create a tracking point? or the tracking point is already there? like i said you can manually position it. u dont need the tracker to tell u where the point should be. or maybe post another screenshot to exactly describe the issue? i dont understand why its problematic for u to do it manually.